# openCV cv::cuda::LookUpTable LUT input

Tags: c++, opencv

i need to implement some image processor classes based on LUT. Classic solution is to slow, so i did little research and found out class [cv::cuda::LookUpTable](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d29/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1LookUpTable.html#afdbcbd3047f847451892f3b18cd018de)

Classic `LUT()` function takes `cv::Mat` obj. LUT as a parameter. `cv::cuda::LookUpTable` does not, there is only method transform to implement which takes source and destination `cv::Mat` (and a stream parameter). I thought about using `LUT()` inside the transform method,but it feels awkward...

So my question is: how to apply LUT using `cv::cuda::LookUpTable` class?

Comment: Go [one level up](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/de/d09/group__cudaarithm__core.html) in the documentation... See the function called [`createLookUpTable`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/de/d09/group__cudaarithm__core.html#ga2d9d9780dea8c5cd85d3c19b7e01979c)?

Comment: yep, found this right after posting this.. Thanks anyway, ill leave this for future generations.